# How to Link to an Alias in Scribble Documentation for a Procedure?

Tags: racket, documentation, scribble

In writing Scribble docs for a function, I'd like to link to a built-in function that has the same name as a different function that's being documented in the same Scribble file. Normally [`@racketlink`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/section-links.html?q=racketlink#%28form._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fmanual..rkt%29._racketlink%29%29) is usable for this purpose (together with something like [`prefix-in`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html?q=prefix-in#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._prefix-in%29%29) to differentiate the two functions in the document namespace), but this doesn't appear to work when the link needs to be within the arguments section of a [`@defproc`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/doc-forms.html?q=defproc#%28form._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fmanual..rkt%29._defproc%29%29) form. For instance:

```
@defproc[(my-proc [f procedure? b:compose])
         any/c]{

 A procedure similar to @racketlink[b:compose]{compose}.

}
```

Note the two usages of `b:compose` above. The latter link to `b:compose` renders simply as `compose` (as expected) but if I try the same code in former instance (in the arguments block), it renders as `(racketlink b:compose "compose")`. How does one "escape" the literal treatment of the content within the `defproc` arguments block? Does this have anything to do with Scribble's notions of "content" and "pre-content" and the process of "decoding"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forms like `@racket[_]`, `@defproc[_]`, etc let you use `#,` (which reads as `unsyntax`) to escape from a *code typesetting* context. So you should be able to write your example as

```
@defproc[(my-proc [f procedure? #, @racketlink[b:compose]{compose})
         any/c]{ .... }
```

Note the space between the `#,` and the `@`, needed to prevent the reader from reading the whole sequence as `unsyntax-splicing`. You can also write the combination as `@#,` because of the way the `@` reader interacts with reader abbreviations like `#,`.

The decoding step that turns pre-content (or pre-flow, etc) into content (or flow, etc) is unrelated. See [the docs for `scribble/decode`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/decode.html).

Comment: This works well. Just one thing though, the rendered `compose` in this case is typeset as normal text (e.g. using serifed font) rather than as code. Anything we can do about that?

Comment: Actually, it looks like this is normal behavior for `racketlink` and not particular to its usage here (it's just more obvious when surrounded by code as it is in this case). I got it to typeset as code by nesting a `racket` inside it: `#, @racketlink[b:compose]{@racket[compose]}`

I had assumed that `@racketlink` was an alternative to `@racket`, intended so that we could link to a different source than it would do on its own, but I guess that's not the case, and the auto-linking happens independently of typesetting with the `@racket` tag.